# Fill xarray dataset variables equal to shape of dimensions

Tags: python-xarray

I'm just starting out with xarray and am having trouble with a particular task that I can't find in the docs. I've created a Dataset with two Dimensions:

`ds = xr.Dataset()
ds['year'] = np.arange(100)
ds['simulation'] = np.arange(1000)`

I want to then add a data variable to the dataset of `np.random.rand()` with *year* and *simulation* as the coordinates and equal to the same shape of the dimensions e.g. (1000,100).

The way I've done it is:

`ds['result'] = (('simulation','year'),np.random.rand(1000,100))`

However, it seems odd to have to specify the shape in the random function, and I'm sure xarray has some magical way of doing this that I can't figure out. What I'm hoping is achievable is something like this:

`ds['result'] = (('simulation','year'),np.random.rand())`

Thus the shape of the random function is infered from the dimensions.

I'd be grateful of any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of construction, it is usually worth being explicit about the creation of your dimensions, coordinates, and variables. I think this does what you were trying to do.

```
ds = xr.Dataset()
ds['result'] = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(1000,100),
                            dims=('simulation', 'year'),
                            coords={'simulation': np.arange(1000), 'year': np.arange(100)})
```

Xarray does allow for some shortcut constructors but when you're just getting started, its probably less confusing to just stick with the standard constructors.

**EDIT 1**

It sounds like you are really looking to use the size of the year/simulation dimensions in the constructor of your result array. This can be done like this:

```
ds = xr.Dataset()

ds.coords['year'] = xr.DataArray(np.arange(100), dims=('year',))
ds.coords['simulation'] = xr.DataArray(np.arange(1000), dims=('simulation',))

ds['result'] = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(ds.dims['simulation'], ds.dims['year']),
                            dims=('simulation', 'year'))
```

Comment: Thanks for this @jhamman. I'm more so talking about after i've established the dimensions of the dataset, how do I quickly add a new data variable to the dataset that automatically conforms to the shape of the dimensions (1000,100). I've edited my original post above.

Comment: okay, short answer. Numpy isn't going to let you do this and xarray doesn't have tools to let you do this at the moment. One problem I'm seeing is that you are missing the distinction between dimensions and coordinates. I'll edit my answer a bit.

Comment: Thankyou @jhamman. Your answer in Edit 1 is exactly what I'm after.